# (a:InternalServiceFault) Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, wsdl, savon

I try to connect soap via savon, I get an error:

```
(a:InternalServiceFault) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Extracted source (around line #85):
    def raise_soap_and_http_errors!
      raise soap_fault if soap_fault?
      raise http_error if http_error?
    end
```

here is my code:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'http://moghim24.ir:8080/Moghim24Scripts/Moghim24Services.svc?wsdl')
response = client.call(:open_tempfllist) do
   message fd: '96/01/01'.to_s, ld:  '97/01/01'.to_s, cust:  '1005'.to_s, pass:  '233344'.to_s
end
render :json => response.body
```

the error happens at this `raise soap_fault if soap_fault?`

Comment: which line is throwing that error ?. Have you tried receiving the object in the block like: `response = client.call(:open_tempfllist) do |locals|` and then `locals.message fd: '96/01/01'.to_s, ld:  '97/01/01'.to_s, cust:  '1005'.to_s, pass:  '233344'.to_s` ?

Comment: message do not send parameters correctly @fanta

Comment: On what line does that error occur? Please post the full error message including the stacktrace. Btw. you can remove the `to_s` calls because the things are already strings.

Comment: @spickermann the question is updated now